# modify the object output when mapping

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object which I am trying to group. The grouping works fine but the output is not in the format I want. I tried different changes but I am not able to make it like the output I want.

**Update:**

Grouping is based on start and end hours, so group classes when all sets of start and end times are the same.So because Math and Gym have the same start and end time, they are group together. Spanish class has 1 set of start and end time as Math and Gym but shouldnt be grouped because it has additional start and end time.

```js
var list = {
  "time_table": [{
    "class_name": "Math",
    "class_status": "open",
    "class_hrs": [{
      "start": "070000",
      "end": "131400"
    }, {
      "start": "131500",
      "end": "132000"
    }]
  }, {
    "class_name": "Science",
    "class_status": "closed",
    "class_hrs": false
  }, {
    "class_name": "Art",
    "class_status": "closed",
    "class_hrs": false
  }, {
    "class_name": "History",
    "class_status": "closed",
    "class_hrs": false
  }, {
    "class_name": "Language",
    "class_status": "closed",
    "class_hrs": false
  }, {
    "class_name": "Gym",
    "class_status": "open",
    "class_hrs": [{
      "start": "070000",
      "end": "131400"
    }, {
      "start": "131500",
      "end": "132000"
    }]
  },{
    "class_name": "Spanish",
    "class_status": "open",
    "class_hrs": [{
      "start": "070000",
      "end": "131400"
    }, {
      "start": "131500",
      "end": "132000"
    },
    {
      "start": "211500",
      "end": "222000"
    }]
  },
  {
    "class_name": "Physics",
    "class_status": "open",
    "class_hrs": [{
      "start": "080000",
      "end": "131400"
    }, {
      "start": "141500",
      "end": "152000"
    }]
  }]
};

function mergeValues(list) {
  let obj = Object.fromEntries(list.map(({
    class_hrs
  }) => [JSON.stringify(class_hrs), {
    count: 0,
    class_name: [],
  }]));
  list.forEach(({
    class_hrs,
    class_name,
  }) => {
    obj[JSON.stringify(class_hrs)].count++;
    obj[JSON.stringify(class_hrs)].class_name.push(class_name);
  });
  return obj;
}

console.log(mergeValues(list.time_table));
```

but I want the **output to be like this**:

```json
{
   "classes":[
      {
         "count":2,
         "class_name":[
            "Math",
            "Gym"
         ]
      },
      {
         "count":4,
         "class_name":[
            "Science",
            "Art",
            "History",
            "Language"
         ]
      },
      ....
   ]
}
```

I tried different ways and to modify `list.map` but I cant get it to work. Any idea how to get this output?

Comment: You can't do this with `map()`. It always returns the same number of elements as the input.

Comment: @Barmar it will be the same number of elements, sorry I think I forgot to add `...` to show the rest of elements in my output

Comment: Why are you using a JSON string as your object keys?

Comment: please add the grouping logic into your question.

Comment: If you want to group all the elements with the same start/end times into a single element in the result, then they won't have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic logic seems OK. You just need to turn `obj` into an array with `Object.values()` in the result and wrap this in in the `{classes: ...}` object.

```js
function mergeValues(list) {
  let obj = Object.fromEntries(list.map(({
    class_hrs
  }) => [JSON.stringify(class_hrs), {
    count: 0,
    class_name: [],
  }]));
  list.forEach(({
    class_hrs,
    class_name,
  }) => {
    obj[JSON.stringify(class_hrs)].count++;
    obj[JSON.stringify(class_hrs)].class_name.push(class_name);
  });
  return {classes: Object.values(obj)};
}

var list = {
  "time_table": [{
    "class_name": "Math",
    "class_status": "open",
    "class_hrs": [{
      "start": "070000",
      "end": "131400"
    }, {
      "start": "131500",
      "end": "132000"
    }]
  }, {
    "class_name": "Science",
    "class_status": "closed",
    "class_hrs": false
  }, {
    "class_name": "Art",
    "class_status": "closed",
    "class_hrs": false
  }, {
    "class_name": "History",
    "class_status": "closed",
    "class_hrs": false
  }, {
    "class_name": "Language",
    "class_status": "closed",
    "class_hrs": false
  }, {
    "class_name": "Gym",
    "class_status": "open",
    "class_hrs": [{
      "start": "070000",
      "end": "131400"
    }, {
      "start": "131500",
      "end": "132000"
    }]
  },{
    "class_name": "Spanish",
    "class_status": "open",
    "class_hrs": [{
      "start": "070000",
      "end": "131400"
    }, {
      "start": "131500",
      "end": "132000"
    },
    {
      "start": "211500",
      "end": "222000"
    }]
  },
  {
    "class_name": "Physics",
    "class_status": "open",
    "class_hrs": [{
      "start": "080000",
      "end": "131400"
    }, {
      "start": "141500",
      "end": "152000"
    }]
  }]
};

console.log(mergeValues(list.time_table));
```